# width of kendo grid according to cell content

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo grid to display data of a csv file. The grid has 6 column [MAC,Module,LogLevel,LogType,LogTime,LogMessage]
The cells of LogMessage column contains large strings, of which only a little part is visible on the grid. I want to display the whole message using horizontal scrollbar but unable to do so, i have tried many things like autowidth property, resizable property but didn't succeed. 
Any idea, how to accomplish this?

Comment: you can use a template with title attribute to show on hover

Comment: @chris show on hover will display in a pop up or in a toast kind of thing, i need the full data in grid itself.

Comment: You can:
1. add template and set title property so that the full string shows up in a on-hover popup.
2. add a button on the left more edge of the column that opens a modal with complete string inside. I have used that in one of my projects.
Why not just use the "edit" feature that displays the full row data in readonly mode in a modal?

Comment: adding to that: 
3. use auto-wrap (overflow: auto) feature which wraps the text into next line.

Comment: @MusabM.Jafri  my employer don't want any button or popup window, need to dispaly entire data in the grid itself

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.MyGridColumns = [
    { 'field': 'Field1', 'title': 'Field1', width: '100px', template: "<div style='overflow:auto;width:100px;'>#: Field1 #</div>" },
    { 'field': 'Field2', 'title': 'Field2' ...etc... },
    ...etc... 
];
```

Comment: Whether this is correct or not is up to the OP. However, a short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.

Comment: @AaronK I tried this. but this gives a horizontal scroll in each and every row of the column,I need a single scrollbar at the bottom and entire data in the grid. Moreover, even in that the data is not complete it shows only some part of string